# Java: What would be the consequence of leaving the package statement out?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and still have a hard time to fully understand the concept of packages and namespaces.

Obviously have classes to be placed in a directory which has the same name as their package. If I have nested packages then the directory path have to map the used package string. Only that the directory path uses Slash, respectively back-slashes for to separate the levels while the package string uses dots.

Now: If I have to reproduce the package string with directories anyway ... **Why can't Java figure out itself to which package a class belongs? Why is the additional package statement needed?**

I ask myself: It should be obvious anyway because of the rule that the containing directory has always the name of the package name. ??

Moreover:
**What happens if I have nested packages and I DO NOT write a package statement in one of the contained classes?**

Comment: Apparently the directory structure of the source code *isn't* actually required to match the package structure, and you can dump a bunch of code from different packages in the same directory and run `javac` to compile them just fine.

Comment: Lets see if packages were not there then how would you define 2 classes with same name ? Wouldnt it be a burden to find where the classes exists ? think in those lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't Java figure out itself to which package a class belongs? Why is the additional package statement needed?

packages are required to resolve the class name conflicts and load the correct class by the [class loaders](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beadf/index.html) (inside JVM)  into the memory.

Assume that you have created two classes with same name as `Utils` class (one `Utils` class for Maths and one `Utils` for Physics), then JVM during class loading time must know & resolve which of this `Utils` class need to be loaded/required. That's where packages will come to the rescue and you can define `com.maths.utils` and `com.physics.utils` packages and add the Utils class into the right package so that we can use it later in any other class by using `import` keyword to specify which `Utils` we are referring to i.e., in short, packages provide the complete full name to the class file.

- Multiple classes (related to same functionality) can be grouped as
  packages.
- Multiple packages (related to same functionality) can be grouped as
  JAR file.

> What happens if I have nested packages and I DO NOT write a package statement in one of the contained classes?

If you have nested packages and if you dont write the `package` name using the `package` keyword at the top of the class, then the code will not compile.

I suggest you read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) more on this.

Answer (score 3):

The fully qualified name of a class is entirely defined by the source file, by combining the package name and the class name. The fully qualified name is never derived from the *location* of the Java source.

Note that Java source "files" do not have to be stored on a file system. They could be stored in a database, on the web, or anywhere else.

So, when the compiler looks for a referenced class (likely by `import` statement), e.g. `org.example.Foo`, it will first check if the class is already compiled and on the Class Path. If not, it will look for the source on the Source Path, so it can compile it too, in case it wasn't already on the list of classes to be compiled.

When using a file system, *locating* that source requires the source to be in a `.java` file of the right name in the right directory, relative to the source root directory specified in the Source Path.

That is only a requirement if the compiler has to go look for the source on the Source Path. If all source files are explicitly listed to be compiled, the source files can technically be anywhere.

E.g. if you have two source files with classes `p1.Foo` and `p2.Bar`, you could technically create two files `x.java` and `y.java` in the same directory and compile them. The compiler would still create `p1/Foo.class` and `p2/Bar.class`.

Doing that will however be very confusing and wouldn't work if compiler has to locate the source. Most compilers will complain (warning or error), to help you, if you don't follow the standard directory structure.